# ¿Existe alguna forma de adaptar una sentencia SQL cuando llega un campo nulo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, oracle

Hola espero que estés bien, ¿hay alguna forma de adaptar una sentencia SQL para que reaccione de acuerdo a si un parámetro llega nulo o no, algo como esto:

```
drop table if exists tabla;

create table tabla (
   id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   fecha date not null
);


insert into tabla (fecha) values (STR_TO_DATE('24-May-2018', '%d-%M-%Y'));

SET @fecha_radicado = STR_TO_DATE('24-May-2018', '%d-%M-%Y');
SELECT  @fecha_radicado; 
SELECT * 
from tabla as  t
where  (
          CASE @fecha_radicado
            WHEN IS NOT NULL THEN  t.fecha = @fecha_radicado
            WHEN IS NULL THEN t.fecha  is NULL
          END;
       ) as fe;
```

Nótese que la consulta tiene el CASE, toma una acción dependido del parámetro que le llegue, ¿existe algún operador que permita realizar este tipo de condiciones dentro de las sentencias CRUD cuando ocurre que uno no sabe si el parámetro es nulo o tiene algo? Si, hay soluciones como estas:

- hacer una sentencia para cada caso, lo cual sería completamente
  ineficiente porque si llegarán 20 parámetros serían casi que (20 C 2) aproximadamente 190 sentencias que tendría que realizar.
- Hacer un método ya en un lenguaje como php, c# o lo que sea que me permita crear una sentencia que se adapte a la necesidad y
  luego esta se ejecute.

Pero agradezco si alguien sabe si algo así se puede hacer dentro de un select. GRACIAS!!

NOTA: Entiendo que hay mutiles motores de SQL, pero según tengo entendido existe el esquema ANSI, por eso pongo la pregunta abierta, sin embargo me interesaría mas si es para MySQL.

Para hacer pruebas:  [rextester.com/JZTO58225](http://rextester.com/JZTO58225)

Comment: en que base de datos, porque ahi hay 3 distintas...

Comment: IF (fecha IS NULL) ó IF(fecha IS NOT NULL)

Comment: Según tengo entendido por criterios ansi, no debería de cambiar mucho, en tal caso podré esa observación, y preferiblemente mysql.

Comment: La mayoria de las bases de datos.. se rieron de los criterios ansi hace rato.. por eso pregunto....

Comment: Y lee sobre coalesce... y si.. podrias hacer una consulta que recibiera 20 parametros y los metiera todos en el query, aun si fueran nulos. Pero eso va a provocar otra cosa que no pensaste, y es que para cada consulta, la db va a hacer si o si un full scan ya que no podra utilizar nunca ninguno de los indices que tiene.

Comment: y creo que lo podriamos discutir mucho mejor en el [chat]

Comment: Leeré sobre el tema, sin embargo me parecería super bueno si la BD por esquema ANSI soportará eso, pero si no esta bien, tenía esa duda. mil gracias.

Comment: es que lo soporta.. el problema es que el query no va a ser performante.. nunca...

Comment: que es lo que quieres ver? puedes mostrar un ejemplo?

Comment: como indico, la idea es que en un procedure me llegue un o varios parámetro este puede ser nulo o contener información. la idea es que sentencia SQL se adapte ha este tipo de parámetro como lo muestro en el ejemplo si es nulo pues que pergunte (tabla.parametrodetabla is null) si no es null (parametro es igual tabla.parametrodetabla)

Comment: si es un SP, puedes hacer que el query se arme dependiendo lo que recibis. con un if por cada paremtro, si viene un dato lo agregas al where, y si no, no lo agregas...

Comment: dependiendo de la implementación podes montarte un "query builder" desde el lenguaje base (php, c#) o como dice @gbianchi con un SP que luego le das `PREPARE` / `EXECUTE` (mysql) o `EXEC sp_executesql` (T-sql)

Answer (score 2):

Esta respuesta no aplica en todos los casos, pero yo usualmente hago algo como esto para utilizar parámetros del tipo *uno o todos* dónde, en el parámetro, el valor especial `null` significa todos los registros.

Para ello me valgo de la función `coalesce`, que devuelve el primer valor no nulo de su lista de parámetros.

Por ejemplo, `coalesce(null, null, null, 1, 2, 3)`, devolverá el valor `1`.

Así, entonces, un ejemplo con 2 parámetros quedaría más o menos como esto:

```
declare @ParamInt int = null;
declare @ParamFecha date = '20180822';

select   t.campo1
       , t.campo2
       , coalesce(@ParamInt, t.CampoInt) CampoInt
       , coalesce(@ParamFecha, t.CampoFecha) CampoFecha
  from MiTabla t
 where t.CampoInt = coalesce(@ParamInt, t.CampoInt)
   and t.CampoFecha = coalesce(@ParamFecha, t.CampoFecha);
```

La principal desventaja de esto está en el rendimiento, pues el motor será incapaz de producir un plan óptimo para cada caso. Esto usualmente no tiene mayores implicaciones si la consulta procesa unos cuantos cientos o miles de registros en un entorno con pocos usuarios, pues representa una tardanza imperceptible para un usuario promedio.

Pero si la consulta debe procesar magnitudes importantes de información o es parte de un sistema con alta concurrencia, entonces suelo intercambiar facilidad en la programación por un mejor desempeño y, aunque suene tedioso, quizás sea mejor escribir esas 200 distintas consultas, o una clase que sea capaz de producir una consulta ad-hoc para cada caso, pues de esta manera el motor será capaz de elegir el mejor plan de ejecución para cada necesidad particular.

Answer (score 1):

En mysql podrías utilizar la función [**case when**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) y la sintaxis seria el siguiente:

```
 select *,(CASE 
          WHEN @fecha_radicado IS NOT NULL THEN @fecha_radicado
          WHEN @fecha_radicado IS NULL     THEN null
         END) as fecha_radicado
 from tabla t
```

Cuando el parámetro fecha no es nulo, te mostrara el dato de **`t.fecha`**

Cuando el parámetro fecha viene nulo, te mostrara **`Null`**.

**editado 1** según lo visto en tu query, editaría tu select de la siguiente forma:

```
 select * 
 from tabla t
 where t.fecha =  
 CASE 
    WHEN @fecha_radicado IS NOT NULL THEN @fecha_radicado
    WHEN @fecha_radicado IS NULL     THEN null
 END
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta respuesta es justamente lo que OP pidio no hacer, especificamente: "hacer una sentencia para cada caso, lo cual sería completamente ineficiente porque si llegarán 20 parámetros serían casi que (20 C 2) aproximadamente 190 sentencias que tendría que realizar."

Comment: Ademas pregunto por el where, no el select...

Comment: Perfecto, talves mal entendí, si no es del apoyo puedo eliminar la respuesta.

Comment: Lo intente hacer como dijiste, pero no responde como debería.http://rextester.com/JZTO58225

Comment: Usaste mal el query, fíjate en la imagen que subí en mi respuesta.

Comment: @JohanInglorion Esto responde la pregunta? si no es asi, por favor quitale el tilde. Pense que justamente habias dicho que no querias hacer algo asi!

Comment: Casí!, solo que mira que si le colocas el parámetro 
SET @fecha_radicado = NULL; no va funcionar bien, porque el va retornar un null y al reptornar el null, pues no va poder ser:

where t.fecha =  
          CASE... 
si no 
where t.fecha IS  
          CASE... 

Por ende no terminaría siendo adaptable. yo creo que no se va poder, yo creo que SQL no permite esas cosas.

Comment: Intenta con el **editado 2** de mi respuesta.

Comment: Solo esto no funcionaría como debería dado que no esta en el where, es el where el que se tiene que adaptar en caso de ser null que prengunte con IS si tiene algo que pregunte con =.